# How to override controller actionresult method in mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

There is one method called Index in HomeController. (It is just default template provided by Microsoft)

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
   }
```

Now What I want is that... override Index method. something like below.

```
public partial class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public virtual ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public override ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Override Index";
            return View();
        }

    }
```

I don't want any modification in existing method like Open-Closed principle in OO design.
Is it possible or not? or Is there another way ?

Comment: You can't do that, you are trying to override a method in the same class it is declared in. You can only override methods in a subclass. If you want to "override" the method in the same class, just replace the old method body with the new one.

Comment: If you can do this, what's the display result when visiting /home/index?

Comment: @verdesmarald: Lets assume that I've made subclass. then how to achive?

Comment: @DannyChen : Result should display "Override Index". means overridden method should be executed.

Comment: To actually override a method, the method has be to in the base class. In your Example, `Controller` is the base class which does not have a method called 'Index'. Did you mean to OverLoad a method?

Comment: If you created a subclass of `HomeController` and moved the code you already have to it it would compile. But I don't think that is what you actually want to do... Perhaps you should explain what you are actually trying to achieve by doing this and someone could point you in the right direction.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel :NO, I'm talking about Override.

Comment: `Override` does not fit into your current context.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel : What is best way if I don't want to change existing Index method and want to make new Index method with different implementation and execute it?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari: So you mean the virtual method(the original one) will never be invoked? Why not remove it?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari, Can you tell us what are you exactly trying to do? so that I can shed some lights.

Comment: @DannyChen : When there is no overridden method exists then It should be invoked.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel : I'm working on an existing MVC3 application. and want to override some existing controller method which is recite in HomeController.

Comment: @DharmikBhandari, That was very general explanation. Anyway, overriding does not apply to the method in the same class.

Comment: @BishnuPaudel : Is there any another way to do this?

Comment: -1, You still haven't explained what you are trying to do, and it has been pointed out to you several times now that what you are saying doesn't make sense. If you have an an old method and you want it to do something different to what it used to do, **just change the method**.

Comment: @verdesmarald : If I change the method name then what about its view?

Comment: Not the name, the implementation.

Comment: @verdesmarald : so you are trying to say that remove old method and make new method with same name but different implementation right?

Answer (score 1):

A `Controller` is a normal C# class, so you have to follow the normal rules of inheritance.  If you're trying to override a method in the same class, that's nonsense and will not compile.

```
public class FooController
{
    public virtual ActionResult Bar()
    {
    }

    // COMPILER ERROR here, there's nothing to override
    public override ActionResult Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

If you have subclasses of `Foo`, then you can override, if the method on the base class is marked `virtual`.  (And, if the subclass doesn't override the method, then the method on the base class will get invoked.)

```
public class FooController
{
    public virtual ActionResult Bar()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class Foo1Controller : FooController
{
    public override ActionResult Bar()
    {
        return View();
    }
}

public class Foo2Controller : FooController
{
}
```

So it works like this:

```
Foo1 foo1 = new Foo1();
foo1.Bar();               // here the overridden Bar method in Foo1 gets called
Foo2 foo2 = new Foo2();
foo2.Bar();               // here the base Bar method in Foo gets called
```

Comment: So you meant to say I should create another controller and inherit it with existing HomeController?

Comment: @DharmikBhandari yes, exactly.

Comment: So when I request home/index then what method will be called?

Comment: For `home/index`, the overriden method in `Home` should get called.