# How to override an Action method in Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using a Cms for Mvc. This Cms has the following Controller:

```
public class OrderController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

For customization needs, I'd like to override the behaviour of this controller and return something different when the same URL is visited by the user. What's the best approach in order to achieve this result?

I tried to inherit the Cms Controller and make the ActionResult an override, following this answer: [How to override controller actionresult method in mvc3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12614603/how-to-override-controller-actionresult-method-in-mvc3)

```
public class OrderController : Cms.Areas.Admin.Controllers.OrderController
{
    public override ActionResult Index(Guid orderItemId)
    {
        // Do extra stuff

        return View();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work. When I try to navigate "admin/order" I still enter in the Cms Controller/Action.

Any suggestion?

NOTE: The Controller I'm trying to override is in another assembly and the action is set to virtual. It's in an Area, therefore the Route is configured inside AreaRegistration.

Comment: `I'm using a Cms for Mvc` - there are a large number of CMS platforms available that use MVC and are customizable not to mention it could also be home grown. No one can answer this without knowing which one you are trying to use and provide customization. Please provide the platform you are using along with how you are trying to hook into that platform.

Comment: Actually, I'm building the Cms itself, so I can change the code as I want. I'm looking for a neat way to implement Controllers that the developers will be able to override

Comment: Ok, next question. `But this doesn't work. ` - looks to me like it might actually be working. Your overriding code does not define a new view, it returns the same result as the method it overrides which would produce the same View. To test this set a break point in your overriding code OR return a different view using a string parameter `View("Other");` Also you cant use keyword `override` without a `virtual` on the parent. Finally you have to take routing into consideration, how are you defining the route so you are hitting your new controller?

Comment: Yes I simplified the code that I pasted here, the actual code does something different. I also tried a breakpoint: it doesn't get hit. I used virtual in the parent.

Comment: At the end I mentioned routing, your routing configuration is probably not setup to hit your controller OR you are using a URL that does not point to it. Make sure that you have your routing configured correctly.

Comment: So there is no way of just overriding a controller without creating a custom route. Is that right?

Comment: If the controller is a class in a different assembly that you are referencing you could create a new controller based on that one. If this controller you want to override is in the same web project as the new one then the non subclassed controller is also still a valid controller and most likely has a valid route. If you want more help please provide additional details like your routing config and where these controllers you want to subclass are found (same assembly or different one).

Comment: I added a note. The controller is in a different assembly, set to virtual. The route is set in the AreaRegistration. I was imagining that since the 2 controllers have the same name, the route would be valid for both. Instead, my new controller is simply ignored. I even tried to specify in the Route the namespace of my controller, thinking that it would prioritise it over the one in the Cms, but if I do so the opposite happens: the controllers of the cms are ignored!

Answer (score 0):

Your request need to use OrderController instead EcommerceOrderController, take a look on your [MVC routes](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me to be a routing question. It doesn't matter if you override the controller if your route still points to the original. If you want a URL to invoke your action, you need to add a route with a higher priority than the one that is currently resolving to the original.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you're saying to leave completely aside the overriding stuff... And just create a different controller and action to point to with a custom route, right?

Comment: Yes. Routes are what controls which controller and action are invoked.